# how to match any part of string?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have an column something like:

```
name         value 
John kennedy 1999
Bill gates   8388383
Obama        11110
```

I need an query that match `1999` if I try get `john` or `kennedy`

I tried it:

```
  cmd.CommandText = "select value from contacts where name like @name";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + name);
```

if `@name` is `john` this returns 0 colums 
   if '@name' is `kennedy` this returns `1999`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put a `%` on both sides of name:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + name + "%");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + name + "%");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the wildcard on both ends of your value:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + name + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that it may have something to do with the case of the parameter value, try setting the column value and the parameter value both to upper or lower case and in your SQL and see if that helps

Comment: the default is for case insensitive comparison. The real bugger here is that the where clause states that the name must end with the value represented by the name variable (otherwise there should be a % in both ends